# How do I create a navigation drawer with non english items?

Tags: java, android, xml, string

This code is stored in res/values/strings.xml

```
    <string-array name="planets_array">
      <item>एक काम</item>
      <item>दो काम</item>
      <item>तीन काम</item>
      <item>चार काम</item>
    </string-array>
```

The array will be passed onto ArrayAdapter which will be used in Navigation Drawer.
However, I want these Items to be referenced using an english name.

**EDIT**

---

This code was done according to changes suggested by Dave.

```
<resources>
    <string name="Mercury">एक काम</string>
    <string name="Venus">दो काम</string>
    <string name="Earth">तीन काम</string>
    <string name="Mars">चार काम</string>

    <string name="app_name">Navigation Drawer Example</string>

    <string-array name="planets_array">
      <item>@string/Mercury</item>
      <item>@string/Venus</item>
      <item>@string/Earth</item>
      <item>@string/Mars</item>
      <item>Jupiter</item>
      <item>Saturn</item>
      <item>Uranus</item>
      <item>Neptune</item>
    </string-array>

    <string name="drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
    <string name="drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>
    <string name="action_websearch">Web search</string>
    <string name="app_not_available">Sorry, there\'s no web browser available</string>
</resources>
```

When I tap on first four items, the respective images of planets dont show up in Navigation drawer but when I tap on last 4 Items (Starting from Jupiter) , It works fine

Comment: referenced using an english name?? what do you mean?

Comment: now only if I could assign something as a=एक काम

Comment: Now you have to work with the string reference names to show the images, not with their values. How do you implement the tap event listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161256/android-reference-a-string-in-a-string-array-resource-with-xml).

As the Android [reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray) says:

```
<item>
    ...
    The value can be a reference to another string resource.
    ...
```

**Solution:**

First, you have to write simple string elements with your english name:

```
<string name="english_planet_1_name">एक काम</string>
<string name="english_planet_2_name">दो काम</string>
<string name="english_planet_3_name">तीन काम</string>
<string name="english_planet_4_name">चार काम</string>
```

And then you can reference them everywhere, even from string-array items:

```
<string-array name="planets_array">
    <item>@string/english_planet_1_name</item>
    <item>@string/english_planet_2_name</item>
    <item>@string/english_planet_3_name</item>
    <item>@string/english_planet_4_name</item>
</string-array>
```

Finally you get both: your planet local names and their english reference name.

Comment: I tried it, but it doesnt seem to work. When I click on it, Its supposed to show me images. but it doesnt show

Comment: Images? Maybe you've a different problem. Expand your question with more code and explain us what are you trying to do.

Comment: see the question now .

Answer (score 1):

You can set the *name* attribute for each **item** but you will have to parse the *strings.xml* file and use getValue from the available set of attributes. Check this SO question out :

[Get name attribute of item of string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224926/how-to-get-name-attribute-of-item-of-string-array)

I haven't had the time to try this though.